# How can join consecutive non-empty lines using sed/awk?

Tags: string, awk, sed, concatenation, lines

How can i join consecutive non-empty lines into a single lines using sed or awk?
An example is given of what I am trying to do.

Input:

```
aaa ff gg
bbb eee eee
ss gg dd

aaa ff gg
bbb eee eee
ss gg dd

aaa ff gg
bbb eee eee
ss gg dd
```

Converts to

```
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you REALLY want a blank line between each data line or not so here's both:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n$/!s/\n/ /;ta' file
```

Unless the last line appended is empty, replace a newline by a space and repeat. Otherwise print and repeat.

If you want empty lines deleted, then:

```
sed ':a;N;/\n$/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

@Schon:@try:

```
awk '{ORS=/^$/?RS RS:FS} {$1=$1} 1;END{print RS}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding explanation too now.

```
awk '{ 
ORS=               ##### Setting Output field separator here.
/^$/               ##### Checking the condition if a line starts from null.
?                  ##### ? means if above condition is TRUE then run following action.
RS RS              ##### set ORS as RS RS means set it to 2 new lines, default value of RS will be new line.
:                  ##### : is a conditional operator which will execute the action following it when condition is FALSE.
FS}                ##### Set ORS to FS, which is field separator and it's default value is space.
{$1=$1}            ##### Re-setting the first field again of line to reflect the new value of ORS.
1;                 ##### making the condition as TRUE and not mentioning the action, so by default print will happen of current line.
END
{print RS}         ##### printing the RS value at last which is new line.
'  Input_file      ##### Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: Could anyone please let me know the reason of - vote here? Will try to improve the code

Comment: Code-only answers are generally [not as helpful as answers with explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Even a little bit of explanation like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43281191/6650102) helps a lot.

Comment: @Aurora0001: Done, adding explanation now.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -00 -pe 's/\n(?!$)/ /g' ip.txt
aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd

aaa ff gg bbb eee eee ss gg dd
```

- `-00` read input in paragraph mode

  - See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for more info and for `-pe` options
  - use `perl -i -00 -pe` for inplace editing
- `s/\n(?!$)/ /g` replace all newlines except the one from blank line with space

Answer (score 1):

A more readable example, less Perl-like:

```
awk '{ if ($0 == "") { print line "\n"; line = "" } else line = line $0 } END { if (line) print line }' file
```